is OTEL_SPAN_EXPORTER a valid exporter in OTLP?
This grafana document
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/monitor-applications/application-observability/instrument/jvm/#otlp-debug-logging
talks about OTEL_SPAN_EXPORTER.

OTEL_SPAN_EXPORTER=otlp,console      Log all spans, and also send spans to
Loki.

I thought OTLP has only these 3 exporters
   OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER 
   OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER  
   OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER

based on https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/sdk-configuration/general/
Is SPAN Exporter a typo in their documentation?
I don't see any other reference to it!
